Why do I get 2 Dell logo's while booting?
When I boot,I get a dell logo, and then some logs, and then another dell logo but this one has an ubuntu loading spinner. When I had tried ubuntu earlier an year back, I only had that dell logo with ubuntu spinner. How do I fix this?
I want that my system has only one logo and then boots into the OS
I have 2 options in the UEFI. One is ubuntu and another is my SSD

Does this answer your question? Want to remove OEM logo during boot in ubuntu 20.04
